# What is this story where children fight war games for land?

Tags: story-identification

When I was younger (early 2000s), I read a young adult novel about a post-apocalyptic earth where the people live in small domed cities because of nuclear fallout and play war games to decide who owns any new clean land.

The main character has been bred to be the best at the game. He has the power to detect the magnetic field of the board pieces which is a requirement to play. He loses his powers for some reason but then wins anyways because his country or teammate cheats and then goes and lives on the island that he won.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Virtual War](http://gloriabooks.com/virtual.html)** by Gloria Skurzynski. 1997.

*When it is discovered that a small group of islands in the Pacific has become livable again, the three federations decide to wage a bloodless virtual war, with the winner to take possession of the island called Nuku Hiva.*

[image: Book cover]

Comment: This is it.  Thanks, Frock. The weird alternate cover confirms it. https://covers.openlibrary.org/w/id/434444-M.jpg

Comment: You're welcome.